# Understanding the rotation math in this code snippet

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, math, 3d, game-development

Here is my code specific to rotation things, given by pseudo-code.

```
var rad = (targettransform.rotationEuler.y) * Math.PI / 180;


var difVec = targettransform.pos - othertransform.pos;

//the difVec.z which means radius
this._targetPos.z -= difVec.z * (1 - Math.cos(rad));
this._targetPos.x += difVec.z * Math.sin(rad);

this.transform.position = this._targetPos;
this.transform.lookAt(targettransform.position, Utils.UnitY);
```

The above pseudo-code is nothing more than just rotating, but I don't understand what `1 - Math.cos(rad)` does, it could be some derivation relative to trigonometric. Would someone explain that math in detail.

### Edit

Sorry, my mistake, the main purpose of the code snippet is to offset "_targetpos" by `vec3(difVec.z * Math.sin(rad),0,this._targetPos.z)` on x-z plane. I manage to rewrite the pseudocode to make sense. It seems that the code snippets only implement the function of keeping relative distance and look at target.

Answer (score 1):

1 - cos(Θ)= 2 sin²(Θ/2) and sin(Θ) = 2 sin(Θ/2) cos(Θ/2), so that you are multiplying the scalar δ by 2 sin(Θ/2), and by a vector in the direction -Θ/2, which is added to the target position.

Comment: i know that trigonometric identity,  it doesn't make any sense to the rotation

Comment: @haoc: I disagree with you.

Answer (score 0):

We can see such terms `(1-Cos(Fi))` and `(Sin(Fi))` in rotation formula around arbitrary axis by [Rodrigues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues'_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation)

But question does not provide enough details to be sure what that code really does.

Comment: I doubt -  shifting z-component by `this._targetPos.z` might denote it becomes zero. Perhaps more clear description of real problem might help.